# Form tag closing automatically (no parent close)

Tags: php, html

The following php code produce a form with 2 inputs tag, the problem is that the form self-closes at exactly after opening it.
There are no other tags closing between (I read it could have been a parent closing inside the form).

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='player.php'>
  <input type='submit' value='Info' name='submit'>
  <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "'>
  </form>";
```

This echo is inside a while fetch array, result of a mysql query.
The result, from chrome dev tools is:

[image: Result]

**EDIT:**

The complete loop is (it is pretty messy and there are a few things that are not best practice):

Basically I am showing a ranking, the top 3 is displayed inside a div, and the rest of the ranking are displayed in a table. The form that sends to the player.php page in the table works, but the one in the div (that is the exact same form without  doesn't).

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        //if top 3 show in a div
        if ($row["rank"] == 1 or $row["rank"] == 2 or $row["rank"] == 3) { 
            
            if($row["rank"] == 1) {
                echo "<div class='center'>";
                echo "<div class='player first'>";        
            }
            else if($row["rank"] == 2) {
                echo "<div class='player second'>";        
            }
            else if($row["rank"] == 3) {
                echo "<div class='player third'>";        
            }
            
            //player img
            echo "<img class='player' src='";
            $position = strpos($row["name"], ",");
            $filename = substr($row["name"], 0, $position);
            if (file_exists("src/players/" . $filename . ".png")) {
                echo "src/players/" . $filename . ".png";
            }
            else {
                echo "src/players/404.png";
            }
            echo "'>
                <h2>" . $row["rank"] . "° - " . $row["rating"] . "</h2>
                <h1>" . $row["name"] . "</h1>";

            echo "<h3>" . $row["country_name"] . "</h3>
                <h5>" . $row["title_name"] . " - " . $row["games"] . " games</h5>";

            //possibility to add to favourites only to login users
            if ($_SESSION["is_login"]) {
                $id_user = $_SESSION["id"];
                $id_player = $row["id"];
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM fav_players WHERE id_user = $id_user AND id_player = $id_player";
                $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
                if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<i class='fas fa-heart' onclick='addPlayerToFav(this, " . $row["id"] . ")'> </i>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<i class='far fa-heart' onclick='addPlayerToFav(this, " . $row["id"] . ")'> </i>";
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "<i class='far fa-heart' onclick=\"window.location.href='account.php'\"></i>";
            }
            
            //the form that doesn't work 
            echo "<form method='POST' action='player.php'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "'>
            <input type='submit' value='Info' name='submit'>
            </form>";
            
            echo "</div>";

            continue;

        }
        
        //the table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "
        <td>" . $row["rank"] . "°</td>
        <td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["rating"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["country_name"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["title_name"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["games"] . "</td>";
        
        //the form that works
        echo "<td class='center'><form method='POST' action='player.php'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["id"] . "'>
        <input type='submit' value='Info' name='submit'></form></td>";
        
        echo "<td class='center'>";
        if ($_SESSION["is_login"]) {
            $id_user = $_SESSION["id"];
            $id_player = $row["id"];
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM fav_players WHERE id_user = $id_user AND id_player = $id_player";
            $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
            if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "<i class='fas fa-heart' onclick='addPlayerToFav(this, " . $row["id"] . ")'></i>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<i class='far fa-heart' onclick='addPlayerToFav(this, " . $row["id"] . ")'></i>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<i class='far fa-heart' onclick=\"window.location.href='account.php'\"></i>";
        }

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo "</table>"
```

Comment: Please show code with while loop. This echo can't generate code on your printscreen.

Comment: Where do you get that result from? From your browser's developer tools by any chance? Because in that view you will see HTML _after_ the browser tried to fix any errors. That is not necessarily the HTML that is send to the browser from PHP.

Comment: @Ivar yes, the problem is that the browser tries to fix an error and closes the form, but I can't understand which error is trying to fix (most of the time it is trying to close a parent that is not closed but I can't figure out which one)

Comment: @imprudenza Could you view the page source (so not the developer tools, but right mouse button -> "View page source" to see the actual HTML that is being produced?  If so please add the relevant HTML to the post.

Comment: The page source is not available because this part of the page is loaded with an ajax request. Btw I found the problem and fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is auto-closing due to a div not closed (the class="center" div). When the div with the top 3 is closed and the first table row is opened the browser auto-closes the form.

Fixed adding the following code before the table echo to close the div only after the 3 player, so after the podium is finished.

```
if($row["rank"] == 3) {
  echo "</div>";
}
```